# Why my code doesn´t display a confirm popup in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function in a script linked to a form in html. When everything is ok the navigator should create 3 cookies and display a confirm popup but it doesn´t display the confirm popup but it creates the cookies. I have tried in firefox, I didn´t do it in chrome because it does extrange things with cookies so i prefered firefox

I'm new to stackoverflow so any advice will be  appreciated

PD: some parts of the code are in Spanish (valor=value nombre=name contraseña=password)

```
function checkForm() {
  var emailValue = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var nombreValue = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var passValue = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
  if(comprobarCookie("email", emailValue)==false){
  if (CheckPass()) {//si las contraseñas coinciden, creamos la cuenta
    createCookie("email", emailValue);
    createCookie("nombre", nombreValue);
    createCookie("pass", passValue);
    var confirm=confirm("!Tu cuenta ha sido creada con éxito!")
    if (confirm==true) {
      location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
    } else {
      txt = "No has creado la cuenta";
    }
  } else {
    alert("las contraseñas no coinciden")
  }
  }else{
    alert("Ya existe una cuenta con ese email")
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `===` instead of `==` in your code.

Comment: Check the console of your browser. There will be a `TypeError`. Then read this about var hoisting: [`var` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: Check with ===  in if statment, Read this
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-operator-in-javascript/

Comment: From wherein the code you call this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using the reserved word `confirm` as your variable to test.  Try replacing:

```
 var confirm=confirm("!Tu cuenta ha sido creada con éxito!")
if (confirm==true) {
  location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
} else {
  txt = "No has creado la cuenta";
}
```

with

```
var user_clicked = confirm("!Tu cuenta ha sido creada con éxito!");
if (user_clicked === true) {
  location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com");
} else {
  txt = "No has creado la cuenta";
}
```

Comment: `confirm` is not a reserved word. But the name of the variable is still one part of the problem. `var` is the other part.

Comment: Agree - bad language on my part; confirm isn't a reserved word but is a builtin function. In this case, var isn't so much the problem as declaring the variable called `confirm` (overwriting the native function) and immediately referencing itself as a function, which it isn't. Working proof is here: https://codepen.io/verdant-spark/pen/wvBBOKY

Comment: Great stuff. Can you accept this answer if you're happy with the solution, please? Cheers!